# Unknown errors from logcat console

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-studio-4.0

I have made an app that fetches/displays videos from the phone's storage. There is this button that when clicked goes to an activity that displays the videos from the phone's storage.

When it's clicked for the first time after launching it from my IDE it opens the activity but when you exit the app and come back later and click the button again it crushes. I have the logcat errors written below. I don't know what's going on. I'll be glad if you guys helped me.

Thank you in advance.

This is my RecyclerView adapter.

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<VideoModel> videoModels;

public VideoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VideoModel> videoModels) {
    this.context = context;
    this.videoModels = videoModels;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lists_of_videos, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final VideoModel vidModel = videoModels.get(position);

    Glide.with(context).load(vidModel.getData()).into(holder.video_thumb);
    holder.duration.setText(vidModel.getDuration());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (vidModel.getData() != null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SelectedVideoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("videoURL", vidModel.getId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return videoModels.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView video_thumb;
    TextView duration;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        video_thumb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_thumb);
        duration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

    }
}
```

}

And this is the Activity

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<VideoModel> videoModelList = new ArrayList<>();
private VideoAdapter videoAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    checkvariables();

    findViewById(R.id.goback).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    checkPermissions();
}

private void checkvariables() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.justarecyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3));

    videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext(), videoModelList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);

}

private void checkPermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);

        } else {
            loadVideos();
        }
    } else {
        loadVideos();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            loadVideos();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied:(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void loadVideos() {
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            String[] projection = new String[0];

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};
            }

            String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

            Cursor cursor = getApplication().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null , sortOrder);

            if (cursor != null){
                int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
                int duration = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);

                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                    int vid_length = cursor.getInt(duration);

                    Uri data = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
                    String duration_format;

                    int sec = (vid_length / 1000) % 60;
                    int min = (vid_length / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
                    int hrs = vid_length / (1000 * 60 * 60);

                    if (hrs == 0){
                        duration_format = String.valueOf(min).concat(":".concat(String.format(Locale.UK,  "%02d", sec)));
                    }else {
                        duration_format = String.valueOf(hrs).concat(":".concat(String.format(Locale.UK,  "%02d", min)
                                .concat(":".concat(String.format(Locale.UK,  "%02d", sec)))));
                    }

                    videoModelList.add(new VideoModel(id, data, duration_format));
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            videoAdapter.notifyItemInserted(videoModelList.size() -1);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

These are the logcat errors

```
2020-11-19 13:39:12.585 15872-15887/com.example.oqpyd E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
2020-11-19 13:39:12.587 15872-15887/com.example.oqpyd E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.isClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.free(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:994)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1022)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:254)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:241)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-11-19 13:39:12.587 15872-15887/com.example.oqpyd E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
2020-11-19 13:39:12.588 15872-15887/com.example.oqpyd E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.isClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.free(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:994)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1022)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:254)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:241)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-11-19 13:39:12.589 15872-15887/com.example.oqpyd E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
2020-11-19 13:39:12.590 15872-15887/com.example.oqpyd E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.isClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.free(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:994)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1022)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:254)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:241)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-11-19 13:39:12.590 15872-15887/com.example.oqpyd E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
2020-11-19 13:39:12.591 15872-15887/com.example.oqpyd E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.isClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.free(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:994)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1022)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:254)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:241)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-11-19 13:39:12.704 15872-15877/com.example.oqpyd I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=125KB, data=82KB
2020-11-19 13:39:12.705 15872-15877/com.example.oqpyd I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=125KB, data=82KB
2020-11-19 13:39:12.705 15872-15877/com.example.oqpyd I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
2020-11-19 13:39:12.963 15872-15872/com.example.oqpyd D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-11-19 13:39:12.966 15872-15872/com.example.oqpyd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.oqpyd, PID: 15872
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{f7adb0f position=23 id=-1, oldPos=11, pLpos:11 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{3a1e42c VFED..... .F....ID 0,92-720,1464 #7f0901a4 app:id/justarecyclerview}, adapter:adapter.VideoAdapter@57bbef5, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@5d248a, context:com.example.oqpyd.PostActivity@c4c3f1d
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5974)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6158)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4085)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3849)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1897)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:414)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:981)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:793)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:720)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:967)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6892)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
2020-11-19 13:39:12.990 15872-15872/com.example.oqpyd I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15872 SIG: 9
`
```

Comment: I think the error is clear IndexOutOfBoundsException in you adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Your error log
**com.example.oqpyd, PID: 15872 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{f7adb0f position=23 id=-1)** 
If you have a look at this two line i hope you can find your error, your view holder try to hold invalid view in position 23.

Comment: Hi Cliff! Thanks for your answer but am still stuck, I've updated my question. Please check it out.

Comment: @JimmyWire  I think this error is refreshing data with completely new content when you again enter and press button. You can easily modify it to fit your needs using notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, previousContentSize);

Comment: If my answer solve your problem and you think it's helpful then mark it accepted. Better luck for your Application.